# How to solve React Native PDF File Problem

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My API return file url. For example, abc.com/a.pdf&token="23123123" like this. I want to download this file. Actually i did. When I run this project on android emulator. But when I export apk(build) and setup my phone I got an error.

Download is unsuccessfull. Emulator works but phone not working.

```
const downloadFile = async url => {
    // Get the app's cache directory
    const {config, fs} = RNFetchBlob;
    const cacheDir = fs.dirs.DownloadDir;

    // Generate a unique filename for the downloaded image
    const regExp = /\/|<|>|\*|"|:|\?|\\|\|/g;
    const filename = url.split('/').pop().replace(regExp, '_');
    // console.log(filename, 'filename');
    const imagePath = `${cacheDir}/${filename}`;
    // console.log(imagePath, 'imagePath');

    try {
      // Download the file and save it to the cache directory
      const configOptions = Platform.select({
        ios: {
          fileCache: true,
          path: imagePath,
          appendExt: filename.split('.').pop(),
        },
        android: {
          fileCache: true,
          path: imagePath,
          appendExt: filename.split('.').pop(),
          addAndroidDownloads: {
            // Related to the Android only
            useDownloadManager: true,
            notification: true,
            path: imagePath,
            description: 'File',
            title: `${userData_token}.pdf`,
          },
        },
      });

      const response = await RNFetchBlob.config(configOptions).fetch(
        'GET',
        url,
      );

      // Return the path to the downloaded file
      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return null;
    }
  };
```

How to download on my phone?